# why isn't my output numbers appending into my list?

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
def lonChain(N):
    final_list = []
    s = list(range(N,10001))
    print (s)
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(s):
        final_list.append(minChain((s[counter])))
        counter += 1
    print (y)
```

the minChain def outputs a number like 13 (assume variable r just to understand it better) (a single number), i.e no list or anything.
but what lonChain does is call the function for the input N. so assume N is 9999, the list would be [9999, 10000]
So the output I'm getting is:

```
13
7
[None,None]
```

But I want the output to be like:

```
[13,7]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the output you would get from a single call to `lonChain()`. First, you're printing s, which should show up as a list, next you're printing the last iteration value of y. So your output should be one list and one number. Please post more of your code.

Comment: You might consider using an IDE or something that can warn you about simple mistakes like *defining `final_list` and then never referring to it anywhere*.

Comment: Can you give us a complete example (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details), with inputs and any other necessary functions, instead of making us try to guess what `minChain` returns or what might be in `N`?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. Please reconsider the desired output and current output

Answer (score 1):

if you want to **append** to your list then you need to use the **append** method

```
y = []
while counter < len(s):
    y.append(minChain((s[counter])))
    counter += 1
```

whereas before you were just overwritting your `y` variable each loop step

Answer (score 1):

You say  "minChain def outputs a number like 13". Usually when people talk about the output of a function they mean the return value

Here it looks like your function is maybe **printing** the result instead of **returning** it

If you don't return anything explicitly, `None` will be returned

This function will print the result, but return `None`

```
def f(x):
    print(x * 2)
```

This function returns the result

```
def f(x):
    return x * 2
```

Comment: Thank You, that was the problem in the code. Sometimes small things cause nasty problems

Answer (score 0):

How are you expecting the data to be appended to the list? You haven't told it to do so at any point: Python can't possibly guess that's what you want.

It seems as if, rather than printing y, you want to append it to final_list: so do that.

```
    final_list.append(y)
return final_list
```